# Postgresql: Use same databases and users between different version (9.5 and 10) Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have successfully installed two different version of Postgresql (9.5 and 10) on my local machine running on port 5432 and 5433. I have created a user and respective databases successfully on Postgresql version 9.5. Now I want to access the same user and databases from Postgresql version 10? Please suggest the required configuration to be done for accessing the same. Thanks.

Comment: This is unclear. More details, please.

Comment: Dump the database from 9.5 and import it into 10

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I have psql 9.5 with a user and multiple databases. Now I installed  psql 10v along side with psql 9.5. When I try to access the list of databases (\list) from psql 9.5, it is showing the my databases or user, but not from psql 10. how can i access it.

Comment: These are different database servers. How should they have the same users or databases unless you create them there as well? I think you should explain your ultimate goal.

Comment: Both installations have their own storage. You could synchronize them with master-master replication or export and import the data once.
Do you need to use them synchronously? Why?

Comment: what do you want to actually achieve? what is the use case?